# Delete specific layers in all PDF documents (batch)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, automation, batch-processing

I have around two hundred wedding name cards and the design is the same, except the name on it changes. I managed to change the names automatically via .csv list + Illustrator batch actions. Quite few files had to be manually changed due to odd kerning between the letters. Now there are few graphic elements which I must delete (the same in all of them).

Is there any automated process (script, batch, different software..) which I can use to delete them all?

I tried to create an action to select the layers and delete them + save (silly), but the step doesn't register names of the layers, so it simply selects all in the batch process.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wy this would be eaier than deleting the element from master source file and just run the batch again. To make it easier split it be the ones that don't need kerning and one that need one and make the master pre-prepared for that extra kerning.

Comment: Well, 40% of them were the ones which needed kerning. Eventually I deleted the graphic elements manually, didn't take as long as I expected.